# Работа в разных браузерах

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка, браузер

Добрый день, умы! )

Изучаю JS, не судите строго.

Объясните, почему скрипты могут работать по-разному в разных браузерах. Т.е. я не имею в виду IE6. У меня на ПК последний хром и мазила. Запускаю скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#scrollTop").fadeTo(0, 0);
    $("#scrollTop").click(function (){
        $("BODY").scrollTop(0);
    });
});

 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if($("BODY").scrollTop() > 400)
     {
         $("#scrollTop").fadeTo(500, 9);         
     }
     else      
     {
         $("#scrollTop").fadeTo(500, 0);
     }
});
```

Работает отлично в хроме, в мазиле при старте дергается и все.

Объясните почему. Объясните как исправить. ) Спасибо.

Comment: Вы бы разместили на http://jsfiddle.net/ код полностью вместе с вёрсткой и сценарием. Возможно, это поведение вызвано особенностями вёрстки.